# how do I create a stored procedure that emails out a snapshot of a view?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view which I need to look at every day that lets me know if the data feeds I need are ready by a set time in the morning.

`select * from vdatafeeds`

I'm want to automate this by having the view load than emailing a snapshot of it to me using a stored procedure.

Is there a way to create a stored procedure that when runs emails out a copy of a view at that moment?

I am using SQL Developer 20.4

TLDR: Basically I just want it to be as if someone loaded the view then copied the contents and pasted it into an email then sent it to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways, certainly.

If view contents is not-that-large (I presume so; who would want to check *million* rows?) and fits a `VARCHAR2` datatype local variable size, you could select row-by-row (in a loop) and **concatenate** values into that variable; at the end, you'd just put it into an e-mail message body.

Another option is to create additional table whose column's datatype is `CLOB` and put view contents in there. Then you'd send an e-mail with **attachment** whose source is that `CLOB` column.

Or, you could create a **file** (using `UTL_FILE` built-in package).

---

Whichever option you choose, such a stored procedure would be **scheduled** using DBMS_SCHEDULER (or DBMS_JOB, its older *brother*, if still available in your database version) to run at desired time (e.g. every morning at 06:50).

---

However, do you really have to check the whole view contents? Can't you "summarize" information to be sent? For example:

```
  - number of rows in a view : 23
  - last updated             : 10.08.2021 23:48
```

That's - in my opition - simipler & easier.

Comment: I view is only a few rows, basically just want it as if someone loaded the view then copied the contents and pasted in to an email then sent it to me